# On export Managed_files With Features No UUID Added

Tags: files, entities, features

I have a custom field  of type 'managed_file' along another field of type - 'file'. This node is exported into feature. The field with 'file' type gets UUID attached while it does not for 'managed_file' field. In the database table 'file_managed', there are UUIDs for all the files included ones uploaded with 'manged_file'. Why is it not including the UUID for managed_file custom fields in the feature? Is there a separate module for this? Any suggestions how to best export/import files? Your help is much appreciated

uuid 7.x-1.0-alpha5+17-dev, uuid_feature 7.x-1.0-alpha3+15-dev, strongarm - 7.x-2.0, Drupal 7.26

Answer (score 0):

I end up creating module for handling assets exporting via Features either as custom field or not. Here is write up
http://margotskapacs.com/2014/04/handling-artifacts-for-custom-module-in-drupal/